# How to remove \0 from the array of strings

Tags: c#, sql, unicode, trim

I have a sql script where after converting from unicode 1200 to unicode 65001 I have that in my .sql file added after character & white space `\0` value. I'm try to use Trim method but it's not work.

What I have right now:

```
string path = @"D:\test.sql";
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    var header = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    //var readText = header.Trim(new Char[] {' ', '*', '.'});
    foreach (string s in header)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Trim(new Char[] { ' ' }));
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In my header I have an array of strings, for example:

```
U\0S\0E\0 \0[\0m\0a\0s\0t\0e\0r\0]\0
```

I was trying to remove `\0`, but this doesn't help me.

Anybody know what I should to do?

Comment: are you familiar with the `Replace()` function.. sounds like you need that instead of Char.. also read the difference between char and string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you wanna remove `\0` but you are trying to remove leading and trailing space, dot, and asteriks. There is nothing about `\0` so far. If you just want to remove `\0` from all lines then you can use `string.Replace` method to replace each occurrence of `\0` with an empty string, and you can apply this to all lines using `LINQ` easily:

```
var header = File.ReadLines(path).Select(line => line.Replace("\0","")).ToArray();
```